# Why is __truediv__ not getting called?

Tags: python, class

I have made a class called `Emulate`. It takes an object and takes the attributes of the object.

```py
class Emulate:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        for attr in dir(obj):
            if attr != '__class__':
                setattr(self, attr, getattr(obj, attr))
```

Now, I want to emulate the integer `1`:

```py
one = Emulate(1)
```

However, I can't use `/` when trying to divide:

```py
print(one / 2)
```

gives `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Emulate' and 'int'`.

But, if I explicitly call `__truediv__`:

```py
print(one.__truediv__(2))
```

it works fine, giving `0.5` as the output.

What is happening here? I thought `x / y` called `x.__truediv__(y)`.

Note: this is not just for division. It is happening for all "magic methods".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Magic methods are looked up on the *class*, not the individual object. Your `Emulate` class does not define `Emulate.__truediv__`, instead adding an *instance attribute* whose value is the `method-wrapper` found on the `int` value.

When you try to use `one / 2`, the lookup of `Emulate.__truediv__` fails.

When you try to use `one.__truediv__`, the lookup of the instance attribute succeeds and produces a method wrapper that can be called with `2` as its argument, giving the observed result.

You can see this in the generated byte code:

```
>>> dis.dis('print(one/2)')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (print)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (one)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (2)
              6 BINARY_TRUE_DIVIDE
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

Here, the opcode `BINARY_TRUE_DIVIDE` is what takes care of trying to find the necessary method using the type of the value referenced by `one`.

```
>>> dis.dis('print(one.__truediv__(2))')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (print)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (one)
              4 LOAD_METHOD              2 (__truediv__)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (2)
              8 CALL_METHOD              1
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

Here, an explicit method lookup on the object `one` produces the value of the `__truediv__` instance attribute you created.